# Send messages on Kakao Talk as an organization

Tags: push-notification, notifications, kakao

I'm new to KakaoTalk and I have to implement a notification process when a user performs some actions on my website. Is there any way to send notifications messages progmatically to the user from the client or server side app? Can you give some link to docs?
Thanks a lot.

I tried to read Kakao docs, but I don't find anything about this topic. I only found solutions about sending messages to friends or myself

Answer (score 0):

(1) User can send it manually.
https://developers.kakao.com/tool/demo/message/kakaolink

(2) It is also possible with the API, but there are limitations.
https://devtalk.kakao.com/t/checklist-to-use-the-messaging-api-and-the-retrieving-list-of-friends-api/118992

(3) Development of notification talk system through dealer
https://business.kakao.com/info/bizmessage/